# Inserting DATETIME to SQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I can't seem to store the datetime to the database.

```
public function add_post($username, $content) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
    $date = date("m/d/Y h:i A");
    $final = strtotime($date);
    $time_posted = date("m/d/Y h:i A", $final);

    $sql =" INSERT INTO POSTS (username, post_content, time_posted)
            VALUES ('$username','$content','$time_posted')";

        return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

It looks like this in the database
[0000-00-00 00:00:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzDoE.jpg)

Here is my posts table: [Posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdgSm.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The date-time field should be formatted as:

```
$time_posted = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $final);
```

Comment: Thanks. Glad it worked. One minor suggestion though - unrelated to datetime / timestamp. Please do take a look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) Prepared Statements to write queries in a rather secure way. If this was a live system, then it might be exposed to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2298301) over the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Help this code for you,

```
public function add_post($username, $content) {
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
   $date = date("m/d/Y h:i A");
   $final = strtotime($date);
   $time_posted = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $final);

   $sql =" INSERT INTO POSTS (username, post_content, time_posted)
        VALUES ('$username','$content','$time_posted')";

    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL time-stamp has a fixed pattern for date time input i.e. "`Y-m-d H:i:s`", If you want to insert date time into database then convert the pattern to the above mentioned one and then try. It'll work